# Resize watermark relative to parent image and keep antialiasing

Tags: php, watermark, antialiasing

I've seen other answers but none address this issue, I have this code

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('w.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');
$stw = imagesx($im)/4;
$marge_bottom = 10;  
$marge_right = 10;

$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);
imagecopyresized($im, $stamp, $marge_right, $marge_bottom, 0, 0, $stw, $stw, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));


header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($im,NULL,100);
```

This works but the watermark (stamp) is jagged after being resized[image]

Watermark Should look like this:

[image]

**Edit:**
here is the solution for anyone with this problem, replace the `imagecopyresized()` function with `imagecopyresampled()`

```
imagecopyresampled($im, $stamp, $marge_right, $marge_bottom, 0, 0, $stw, $stw, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
```

Comment: What does *crushed* mean in the context of your question? What happen if you change the value of `$stw`?

Comment: The watermark (PNG24) gets jagged and pixelated, I will add an image on how it should look

Comment: Image added, notice the watermark's  quality

Comment: I think that's a result of using jpg.  But it will be really hard to answer without know what your other function calls are doing.

Comment: I would use a vectorial format like SVG.

Comment: I don't have other functions this is all the code, I get the same result if I save in PNG

Comment: Thank you both, I've fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) instead of `imagecopyresized`:

```
imagecopyresampled($im, $stamp, $marge_right, $marge_bottom, 0, 0, $stw, $stw, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
```

From the manual:

> imagecopyresampled() copies a rectangular portion of one image to another image, smoothly interpolating pixel values so that, in particular, reducing the size of an image still retains a great deal of clarity.

Comment: Yes that did the trick! 
the process is a bit slower but I can live with that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the ins and outs of the code you have here. However, I do know that any image that scales down must keep its aspect ratio in order to appear the same at a smaller size. If you use absolute values to define your images width and height when scaling down, the chances of jagged edges in your image is higher because the image is not keeping its aspect ratio at smaller sizes. Therefore, instead of defining an absolute value, use a dynamic value. So for example, instead of using something like 10px or convert into percentage (%).

Comment: Well `imagecopyresized()` only accepts numbers and the stamp  image is squared, also this is all the code in this script

Comment: @nodws ahh...k, then makes sense why the function needed to be changed

Comment: @A.L no, suggesting that would be insane

Comment: In other words, how do you use `1.000em` with `imagecopyresized()`?

Comment: @A.L The first example here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.phpv  shows the use of percentage, not sure em can be used. But even on this page it explains how imagecopyresampled will produce smoother results, so I guess it makes figuring out how to do that with imagecopyresized a moot point

Comment: You can improve this answer by providing an example to show how you *use something like 10px or convert into percentage (%)*.